# jquery ajax form submit via java servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsp, accordion

I am trying to submit a form via Ajax/Jquery and get a response back from a Servlet within an accordion step process but for the life of me, I cannot figure this out. I have the form working on it's own and I have the accordion working on it's own, but when I put these two together it doesn't work.

here is the code as I have put it together:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('label.form-field-label-required').append('&nbsp;<strong>*</strong>');

// accordion functions
var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({
      event: false,
      autoheight: true,
      animated: "slide",
});
var current = 0; 

$.validator.addMethod("pageRequired", function(value, element) {
    var $element = $(element)
    function match(index) {
        return current == index && $(element).parents("#accordion").length;
    }
    if (match(0) || match(1) || match(2)) {
        return !this.optional(element);
    }
    return "dependency-mismatch";
}, $.validator.messages.required)

var v = $("#cmaForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function() { 
         $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"ActionServlet",
                    data:"name="+name+"&sex="+gender,
                    success: function(response){

                    // Change only the header of the file.
                    $("h1").text(response);
                    },
                }); 
                            if (v2.form()) {
                        accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
                        current = 1;
                    }
                }
        });
```

the form code:

```
    <h4><a href="#">Employee Personal Information</a></h4>
    <div>
            <form name="cmaForm" id="cmaForm" action="" method="post">
<h1 style="text-align:center">Hello Guest</h1>
      <p>Please fill out your name and gender: <br></br>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"/> Male.<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/> Female. </p>
      <p>
         <input name="formNext1" type="submit" class="open1 nextbutton" value="Next" alt="Next" title="Next" />
      </p>
    </form>
```

What is supposed to happen is, upon success, the H1 text should change to reflect the input data and then the first accordion closes and the second one opens up. So far all that happens is a page refresh and then this shows up in the address bar:

```
http://localhost/test/index.htm?name=bnhjhj&sex=female#
```

but nothing else happens.

I've only included the first accordion code to limit the amount of code on the screen. If you need the rest of it, I can post it.

Thanks in advance.

SERVLET CODE

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public ActionServlet()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(req, res);
    }

       public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
               throws ServletException, IOException {
                    String name= request.getParameter("name");
                    String gender= request.getParameter("sex");
                    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                        if(gender.equals("male")){
                            out.print("Hello Mr "+ name +" your request was sent successfully.");
                            }
                            else{
                            out.print("Hello Miss "+ name +" your request was sent successfully.");
                        }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you made your call to jQuery ajax(), change the data property to be in JSON instead of a string. Example

```
$.ajax({ ..., data: { "name": name, "gender": gender }});
```

Comment: Okay, awesome, that got me to the next accordion, but the H1 Header didn't change with the input data :

Comment: i would try using alert() to see if you're getting any response back from the server, and then try to update the DOM.

Comment: also, if you get an error, you won't know about it because success doesn't get called. You may want to add an "error" property with a callback so if something bad happens, you can get some details about it.

Comment: Well the Eclipse console shows that I'm definitely hitting the server and the servlet. This is the first line of the server response: ERROR [[ActionServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet ActionServlet threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException BUT i am not getting the alert that I put in after the success: function(response)

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem on the server-side.